# Inferno + TypeScript Isomorphic Application

Tags: typescript, express, server-side, isomorphic-javascript, infernojs

I'm trying to create an isomorphic application using Express and Inferno. Unfortunately, I can not find any similar projects on the Internet. I tried to create my own using [Razzle](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/tree/next/examples/with-inferno). But, unfortunately, I did not manage to connect TypeScript, despite the full correspondence of all config files.

The question itself: how can this be done easily? Which steps should i do for making this?

P.S. Maybe there are some React examples with TypeScript that can easily be remade for Inferno?

Comment: Yes, there are TS+React examples that can be remade for Inferno. Asking for off-site resources is off-topic on SO. You can remake it by replacing React imports with respective Inferno and using jsxFactory option, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html . Consider reasking a question if you will have specific problem with your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i made this myself (Inferno, Typescript, Routing, FuseBox): https://github.com/MrFoxPro/inferno-isomorphic-tempalte